# Finding the roots of $z^4=(\sqrt{3}+ i)^4$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to solve this exercise (finding the roots of):

$$z^4=(\sqrt{3}+ i)^4$$

This can be written as $[2\cdot (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2})]^4$.

From here it is easy to see that a root is $z_0=2\cdot e^{i\cdot \frac{\pi}{6}}$.

How can I find the other three roots?

Simply $2\cdot e^{i\cdot \frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2\cdot \pi\cdot k\cdot 
i}{4}}$?

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You already have them by substituing k= 0, 1,2,3. These are various numbers. That's how works de Moivre formula

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $z^4= a^4\rightarrow  z\in\{\pm \;a, \pm\; ai \}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
z^4=(\sqrt{3}+i)^4\\
z^4=16e^{2n\pi+\frac{4\pi}{6}}
\\z=2e^{\frac{n\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6}}
\end{align}
$$

This gives four roots for $n=0,1,2,3$ after that it repeats with a $2\pi$ period

Note: you shouldn't take the $2n\pi$ term before you take the 4th power or you'll miss the other solutions

Answer (score 0):

In general,

$$z^n= z_0^n$$

$$z=z_0(1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$z=z_0e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}k}$$where $$k\in[0,n-1], k\in \mathbb N$$